# Doctrine always only looks at the owning side of a bidirectional association for updates

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I know what owning side and inversed side is, but I can't understand the following from the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html):

> Since Doctrine always only looks at the owning side of a bidirectional
>   association for updates, it is not necessary for write operations that
>   an inverse collection of a bidirectional one-to-many or many-to-many
>   association is updated. This knowledge can often be used to improve
>   performance by avoiding the loading of the inverse collection.

The following code is also from the doc:

```
<?php
// This code is from doc
// Remove by Elements
$user->getComments()->removeElement($comment);
$comment->setAuthor(null);
$em->flush();
```

So the above code is redundant? I can just remove the association from the comment(owning) side:

```
//This is my code
$comment->setAuthor(null);
$em->flush();
```

Am I correct? Or can you provide any examples? Thanks!

**Edit:**

I found the great explanation of "owning side of an association for changes" in the [doc.Important concepts](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts).

Also, thanks AlixB, your answer is correct, just as explained in the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is correct for Doctrine to update a field. On flush, Doctrine will remove the comment from the database. BUT you need to think that some actions could be ended later in the code. So if you don't process bot the owning and the inverse side, in your logic you will have a comment with a null author, but in the list of comments of a user. ANd, for instance, if after remove you iterate on the list of comments of this user, you will have something wrong.

Do you understand what I mean?